# Plotting a pie chart on tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and I am trying to create a pie chart on tableau using the following sample data. Could some one help me out.

[image]

I have added Sum and date to the measures side and t1 , t2 to the dimensions side. But I end not getting any pie chart as expected.I wanted to just visualize how the sum of 100 can be shown as percentages of t1 and t2 on the pie chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is pretty simple. you will have to rearrange your data as below.

Date               Section       Count

1/1/2012           t1         50
1/1/2012           t2         50
2/1/2012            t1            45
2/1/2012            t2            55

and then refer to the [instructions](http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/PieChart_1/Sheet1?%3aembed=y&%3adisplay_count=no).

Comment: If you have a lot of data to reshape like this, look for the Excel Reshaping plugin on Tableau's web site (query reshape and excel in the Knowledge Base). Also, check out the other chart types using the "Show Me" panel. There are usually better alternatives than pie charts since pie wedges are very difficult to compare for size differences.